# How to display a record from a iterator

Tags: java, iterator, jtextarea, display

How do you display a record from a iterator?

I know how to look for a record, the problem is that I need to display it.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
public void getFirst()
{
    iterator = rosterList.listIterator(0);
    setMembers(iterator.next());
    System.out.println("Success!");
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        txa.append(iterator.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) method to get the value the iterator points to, which you can then convert to a string. E.g.:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    txa.append(iterator.next().toString());
    // Here -----------^
}
```

Comment: I did try that earlier. But it is only displaying the record identifier. We have to display the entire record, like the name, id, DOB etc...

Answer (score 1):

Just do `iterator.next()` it gives you the current object in the iteration. It is the same type as the objects of the list

After that you just have to retrieve the property you want from that object. For instance `iterator.next().toString()`